# canvas.drawPosText is deprecated since API 16. What's the replacement?

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

`canvas.drawPosText` is an API that allow characters in text to be drawn in different positions on the canvas. However it is deprecated since Android SDK API 16, as it doesn't support glyph composition (according to the deprecate document).

Given it is deprecated, what's the replacement API for it?

Comment: How about drawText: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawText(java.lang.CharSequence,%2520int,%2520int,%2520float,%2520float,%2520android.graphics.Paint)

Comment: Is there a way to position differently for each character in the text for `drawText`?